Having an issue with delimiters in CSV and powershell
Having an issue with getting a csv that is converted from an email into a readable report, the script functions mostly but returns System.Object[] in all three columns instead of the value when I try to move them with my script into corresponding columns. The top image is my source file and the second image is the current output.


Code
$inputcsv = 'C:\Users\Testing\04052024\4032024 DTV Report input.csv'
$outputcsv = 'C:\Users\Testing\04052024\4052024 724 Report Output1122.csv'
$data = Get-Content $inputcsv
$parsedData = @()

      for ($i = 0; $i -lt $data.Count; $i += 2) {
      $siteSelection = $data[$i] -replace "Midtier: lcahncr1.lcahncrkc.net Site selection: ", ""`
                           -replace 'Midtier: lcahncr2.lcahncrkc.net Site selection:',''`
                           -replace 'Midtier: lcahncr3.lcahncrkc.net Site selection:',''`
                           -replace 'Midtier: lcahncr4.lcahncrkc.net Site selection:',''`
                           -replace 'Midtier: lcahncr5.lcahncrkc.net Site selection:',''`
                           -replace 'Midtier: lcahncr6.lcahncrkc.net Site selection:',''`
                           -replace 'Midtier: lcahncr7.lcahncrkc.net Site selection:',''`
                           -replace 'Midtier: lcahncr8.lcahncrkc.net Site selection:',''`
                           -replace 'Midtier: lcahncr9.lcahncrkc.net Site selection:',''

$components = $data[$i+1] -split ", "

$functionalDevices = ($components | Where-Object {$_ -match "Functional Devices=\d+" }) -replace "Functional Devices=", ""
$NotfunctionalDevices = ($components | Where-Object {$_ -match "Not Functional Devices=\d+" }) -replace "Not Functional Devices=", ""
$TotalDevices = ($components | Where-Object {$_ -match "Total Devices=\d+" }) -replace "Total Devices=", ""

$parsedObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Site= $siteSelection
    "Functional Devices" = $functionalDevices
    "Not Functional Devices" = $NotfunctionalDevices
    "Total Devices" = $TotalDevices

    }

$parsedData += $parsedObject

  }

     $parsedData | Export-Csv -Path $outputcsv -NoTypeInformation


Please do not post textual data as image.. [edit] your question and replace the (at least top image) by the text when opened in Notepad

The issue is related to the fact that $functionalDevices, $NotfunctionalDevices, and $TotalDevices are being assigned arrays instead of individual values. When you use -replace with a regular expression, it returns an array if there are multiple matches found. To fix this issue, you can modify your script to ensure that you're only extracting the first match for each component.
Try something like this:
$functionalDevices = ($components | Where-Object {$_ -match "Functional Devices=\d+" })[0] -replace "Functional Devices=", ""


can't test but it appears powershell cant interpret the arrays as single values which is why you're seeing "System.Object[]" result.
it's being treated as an array rather than a single string/int.
try piping it with Select-Object -First 1
so they'd look like $functionalDevices = ($components | Where-Object {$_ -match "Functional Devices=\d+" }) -replace "Functional Devices=", "" | Select-Object -First 1
etc.
